# D3 Selection Works while svg Selection Doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I have

```
var svg = d3.select(.....)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 1500)
            .attr("height", 850);
```

Later on I have

```
svg.SelectAll(......)
   .
   .
   .on("mouseover", function(){
        d3.select(this).style(.....
   }
```

Inside the anonymous function, I change the style of some svg contents.
But I tried to do

```
svg.select(this).style....
```

instead of

```
d3.select(this).style....
```

and it broke.

What is the reason why *d3* must be used instead of *svg*?

Comment: Your question title is misleading. `d3` is the D3 library's object, while `svg` is just some variable created by the code you show.

Comment: Now, I can guess, but it'd be best if you told us how exactly "it broke" when you tried to call the `select` method of an SVG element… got any error?

Comment: I certainly apologize for this. I understand the difference between d3 object and svg variable. I guess what my question is that, since my svg components are on svg, why do I need to use the d3 object to change the attribute of my svg component?

Comment: Thanks Lars for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d3.select()` accepts two types of arguments -- a selector string and a DOM element. `selection.select()` (`svg.select()` in your case) accepts *only* a selector string. You're passing in a DOM element, which breaks the code (and you get an error message accordingly).

Comment: To be more precise, `selection.select()` does accept a selector string as well as a function returning an element. The main difference between both methods is the fact that `d3.select(node)` will return a selection containing the one `node`, whereas `selection.select()`will return a subselection of `selection`retaining its initial grouping.

Comment: @altocumulus Not sure where you got that from; it doesn't work for me (http://jsfiddle.net/9otv235t/).

Comment: The [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#select) told me ;-) It's a matter of scope in your anonymous function returning the `this`node. Inside the function `this` points to `window`. This could be easily worked around with a closure. See my [update](http://jsfiddle.net/9otv235t/3/).

Comment: Oh of course, you're right. Thanks for the addition!